# Changing source of iframe reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I change the source of my Iframe but it reloads the page, and I can't figure out why.
HTML:

```
        <div id="fill">
            <iframe id="frame" style="width: 88.97vw; height: 90vh" src="html/question1.html">

            </iframe>
        </div>
            <form>
                <input type="submit" value="question1" class="menuBut">
                <input type="submit" value="question2" class="menuBut">
                <input type="submit" value="question3" class="menuBut">
            </form>
```

My page is a quiz, and I want the iframe to change questions when a button is pressed. 
JQuery:

```
var url;

function callMe() {
    $(".menuBut").click(function () {
        $("#frame").remove();
        url = this.value;
        $("#fill").append('<iframe id="frame" width="200px" height="700px" src="html/' + url + '.html"></iframe>');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    callMe();
});
```

The source is supposed to be changed to the page "html/questionX.html" where X depends on the button pressed. However it doesn't adapt the iframe, instead it refreshes the page. Support please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a form if you just want buttons, and you certainly don't need submit buttons to trigger Javascript.  Just use regular buttons, like this...

```
<div id="fill">
    <iframe id="frame" style="width: 88.97vw; height: 90vh" src="html/question1.html"></iframe>
</div>
<button type="button" value="question1" class="menuBut">question 1</button>
<button type="button" value="question2" class="menuBut">question 2</button>
<button type="button" value="question3" class="menuBut">question 3</button>
```

The submit buttons were causing the form to be submitted, which basically posts all the form data to the page itself, causing a reload.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="button"` on your buttons instead of `submit`. Otherwise, the buttons submit the form which causes the page to reload.

Answer (score -1):

`return false;` at the end of the click event handler, to stop the propagation and the default behaviour of the submit button.